# Do we *have* to use data: URIs (readAsDataURL) to use File objects with <img /> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, data-uri

I understand the current common technique for creating an `<img />` element in JavaScript from a client-side `File` object goes something like this.

(The `File` object would originate from a file drag-and-drop handler or `<input type="file" />` `change` event.)

```
function showImageFile( file: File ): void {

    let rdr = new FileReader();
    rdr.readAsDataURL( file );
    rdr.onloadend = function() {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = rdr.result;
        document.body.appendChild( img );
    };
}
```

I don't like this - the notion of serialising what could be a multi-megabyte image to a base64-encoded string (thus using 1.3x *more* memory on top of the existing `File` object) as well as incurring the cost of deserializing the string back into the `<img />` element - ultimately this will cause at least 3 instances of the image's data to exist in memory. This seems very wasteful and inefficient to me, and JavaScript applications already have a bad rep for excessive memory consumption.

I noticed that for the `<video>` and `<audio>` elements (`HTMLMediaElement`) that MDN recommends doing something like this:

```
function showVideoFile( file: File ): void {

    let video = document.createElement('video');
    video.srcObject = URL.createObjectURL( file ); // createObjectURL creates a URI alias to the existing file instance in-memory
}
```

(with the caveat that if `srcObject` is ever replaced or the `video` element removed, the previous `objectURL` must be manually released using `revokeObjectURL`.

Is there any way to do the same thing for `<img />`? (I don't see a `srcObject` property on `HTMLImageElement` and `HTMLImageElement` does not derive from `HTMLMediaElement`). Searching online for "javascript image files without data URIs" unfortunately only returns pages *about* `readAsDataURL` which is the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set its… `src`.

```js
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function () {
    if (this.files.length !== 0) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After sacrificing more minutes down dark and dirty information mines at Google I found a nugget of coal in this December 2014 article http://bytes.schibsted.com/the-magic-of-createobjecturl/ that says that the `HTMLImageElement`'s `src` attribute *does* actually accept an object URI (phew!)

MDN also cover it on their website, albeit buried somewhat: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images

In short, my `showImageFile` function can be updated like so:

```
function showImageFile( file: File ): void {

    let objectURI = URL.createObjectURL( file ); // looks like "blob:http://mywebsite/{guid}"

    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = objectURI ;
    document.body.appendChild( img );
}
```

Or if the `img` element will be reused:

```
var img: HTMLImageElement;

function showImageFile( file: File ): void {

    let oldSrc = img.src;

    let objectURI = URL.createObjectURL( file );

    img.src = objectURI;

    if( oldSrc ) URL.revokeObjectURL( oldSrc );
}
```